# Mutating Webhook does not invoke endpoint because certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, webhooks, pem, certificate-authority

I am developing a [mutating webhook](https://medium.com/ovni/writing-a-very-basic-kubernetes-mutating-admission-webhook-398dbbcb63ec) with [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start) and as I understand, the API end-point should be `https`. The certificate and key of the API server should be signed with the CA of the cluster itself so as to get around issue of self-signed certificates. And, for that, the following are the recommended steps:

1. Create key - `openssl genrsa -out app.key 2048`
2. Create CSR - `openssl req -new -key app.key -subj "/CN=${CSR_NAME}" -out app.csr -config csr.conf`
3. Create CSR object in kubernetes - `kubectl create -f csr.yaml`
4. Approve CSR - `kubectl certificate approve csr_name`
5. Extract PEM - `kubectl get csr app.csr -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}' | openssl base64 -d -A -out app.pem`

**Notes**
1. The `csr.conf` has details to set-up the CSR successfully.
2. The `csr.yaml` is written for the kuberenetes kind `CertificateSigningRequest`.
3. The `csr_name` is defined in `CertificateSigningRequest`.
4. The `spec.request` in `csr.yaml` is set to `cat app.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n'`.
5. The `app.pem` and `app.key` are used to set-up the `https` end-point.

The end-point is definitely reachable but errors out as:

```sh
Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "com.me.webhooks.demo": Post https://webhook.sidecars.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

How do I get around the `certificate signed by unknown authority` issue?

References:
1. [Writing a very basic kubernetes mutating admission webhook](https://medium.com/ovni/writing-a-very-basic-kubernetes-mutating-admission-webhook-398dbbcb63ec)
2. [Diving into Kubernetes MutatingAdmissionWebhook](https://medium.com/ibm-cloud/diving-into-kubernetes-mutatingadmissionwebhook-6ef3c5695f74)

Comment: I get the same error when I upgraded to api version `certificates.k8s.io/v1`. Did you upgrade as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't need to be signed with the cluster's CA root. It just needs to match the CA bundle in the webhook configuration.

Comment: Ok. How do we ensure the 'match'? Example please.

Comment: You can see the field in your first example link: `caBundle: ${CA_BUNDLE}`. They give you a command to generate a value for that field. Basically you need to fill in your CA cert.